How to simultaneously and manually perform feature selection and hyperparameter tuning using multiple performance measures?
I am exploring the possibility of simultaneously performing feature selection and hyperparameter tuning using multiple performance measures. I am building ecological niche models, and it is advised to use multiple performance measures rather than just one. I came across this post, but it only uses a single performance measure. One of the comments mentioned: "For each specific feature subset, tune the hyperparameters of the learner in the inner resampling loop, and after you tune them, evaluate them in the middle resampling loop to select the optimal feature subset."
In the mlr3 book, an example is given for multi-objective tuning:
instance = ti(task = tsk("sonar"),
  learner = lrn("classif.rpart", cp = to_tune(1e-04, 1e-1), minsplit = to_tune(2, 64), maxdepth = to_tune(1, 30)),
  resampling = rsmp("cv", folds = 3),
  measures = msrs(c("classif.tpr", "classif.tnr")),
  terminator = trm("evals", n_evals = 30),
  store_models = TRUE)
tuner = tnr("random_search") 
tuner$optimize(instance)

The same example for conducting feature selection based on random search with multiple performance measures would be:
instance = mlr3fselect::fsi(task = tsk("sonar"),
  learner = lrn("classif.rpart"),
  resampling = rsmp("cv", folds = 3),
  measure = msrs(c("classif.tpr", "classif.tnr")),
  terminator = trm("evals", n_evals = 30))

fselector = mlr3fselect::fs("random_search")
fselector$optimize(instance)

Also, I was wondering if it was possible to manually nest the two processes? If so, how?
UPDATE
From what I understand from the comment on the mentioned post above (but I am really not sure), I have listed below the steps I would have taken with a reproducible example. In this example, I automatically select the first row to select the best combination of hyperparameters and feature subsets. But in reality, I created a function to select the best combination.
task = tsk("sonar")

##########################################################
## Step 1: Generate all possible combinations of feature selections as follows:
feature_sub <- expand.grid(lapply(c("V1", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17", "V18", "V19", "V2"), function(x){c(TRUE, FALSE)}))
names(feature_sub) <- c("V1", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17", "V18", "V19", "V2")
feature_sub <- apply(feature_sub, 1, function(x){names(which(x == TRUE))})


learner_glmnet <- mlr3tuningspaces::lts(mlr3::lrn("classif.glmnet", predict_type = "prob"))
learner_rpart <- mlr3tuningspaces::lts(mlr3::lrn("classif.rpart", predict_type = "prob"))
learners <- c(learner_glmnet, learner_rpart)

tuner <- mlr3tuning::tnr("mbo")

##########################################################
## Step 2: Evaluate the model's performance with the optimized hyperparameters on the selected feature subset

## Loop over the learners
for(learner_ID in 1:length(learners)){
  
  cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2, outfile = paste0("C:/Users/Downloads", "/", "output.txt"))
  doSNOW::registerDoSNOW(cl)
  
  ## Loop over the subsets of features
  subset_list <- foreach::foreach(feature_sub_ID = 1:2, .errorhandling = "pass", .packages = c("dplyr")) %dopar% {
    
    set.seed(1)
    
    ## Retrieve the task
    modified_task <- task
    
    ## Create a tuning instance 
    instance <- mlr3tuning::ti(task = modified_task$select(c(feature_sub[[feature_sub_ID]])),
                               learner = learners[[learner_ID]],
                               resampling = mlr3::rsmp("cv", folds = 3),
                               measures = mlr3::msrs(c("classif.sensitivity", "classif.specificity", "classif.auc")),
                               terminator = mlr3tuning::trm("evals", n_evals = 5))
    
    ## Run the tuning process  
    tuner$optimize(instance)
    
    ## Retrieve the best combination of hyperparameters
    best_hyperparameter_comb <- data.frame(instance$result)[1,]
    
    ## Add columns
    best_hyperparameter_comb$learner_ID <- learner_ID
    best_hyperparameter_comb$subset_ID <- feature_sub_ID
    
    return(best_hyperparameter_comb)
    
  }
  
  parallel::stopCluster(cl)
  
}

############################################
## Step 3: Retrieve the best subset
best_subset_comb <- subset_list[[1]]

Since I have 12 features, I have 4096 subsets of features to test, which is a lot. Additionally, I am not sure if this is representative of a backward selection (which is the type of selection I would like to use). Any advice on how to simultaneously and manually perform feature selection (backward selection) and hyperparameter tuning would be greatly appreciated because I am totally lost.

Not entirely clear to me what you want to do. With multiple objectives, you can't automatically select a "best" configuration, so this wouldn't work in the context of automated feature selection.

@LarsKotthoff thank you for your comment. Yes, I understand well, but I was rather wondering how I could do that manually assuming that I determine the best configuration myself. Hence my question in my post: Also, I was wondering if it was possible to manually nest the two processes? If so, how?

I think that's described in the mlr3 book: https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/chapters/chapter6/feature_selection.html#sec-fs-wrapper

@LarsKotthoff thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any examples on how to manually nest the tuning process and feature selection.

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, all you need to to is replace the learner in the examples in the book with an autotuner.

@LarsKotthoff thank you for your comment. I don't think that's possible because an autotuner does not work with multiple performance measures (thus multiple objectives). Therefore, I am looking for a way to integrate the tuning process with multiple objectives and feature selection with multiple objectives as described in the referenced post, but manually.

If you want to do it manually, you could just do exactly that -- run tuning manually, get the result, then run feature selection manually, get the result, etc.

@LarsKotthoff thank you for your comment. Ok, but it is noted in one of the comments in the referenced post: For each specific feature subset, tune the hyperparameters of the learner in the inner resampling loop, and after you tune them, evaluate them in the middle resampling loop to select the optimal feature subset. From what I understand (but I am really not sure), the steps would be (see my comment below):


Generate all possible combinations of feature selections, 2) Optimize the model's hyperparameters for each given feature subset, 3) Evaluate the model's performance with the optimized hyperparameters on the selected feature subset, 4) Identify the best feature subset among all those tested.


Yes, you can do that automatically with an autotuner. But as you say above, that's not what you want because you have multiple performance measures. At this point, I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for. It sounds like you're trying to automate something that cannot be automated.

@LarsKotthoff Sorry if that wasn't clear. No, I'm not looking to automate the processes. I just want to know the right way to do this manually. I've updated my post with the steps I thought to combine the two processes manually. If the steps seem correct to you, then that's great, you're answering my post.

Yes, that sounds correct.

@LarsKotthoff Thank very much. Unfortunately, I have 2 problems that I am not sure how to solve. The first is that since I have 12 features, I have 4096 subsets of features to test, which is a lot. Additionally, I am not sure if this is representative of a backward selection (which is the type of selection I would like to use). Secondly, I don't see how to do nested resampling with multi-objective tuning. I haven't found an example with TuningInstanceMultiCrit(). Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I am feeling quite stuck.

You don't need to do all subsets in a backward selection; see https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/chapters/chapter6/feature_selection.html#sec-fs-wrapper for an example for forward selection. Nested resampling for multiple objectives works in principle the same way as for single objectives, except that you can't automatically choose the "best".

@LarsKotthoff Thank you very much. I would like to include fselector = fs("sequential", strategy = "sbs") with FSelectInstanceMultiCrit but I don't know how to combine it with the ti() in my code. I have updated my post with what my code looks like.

You can't because you can't automatically select the best configuration with multi-objective optimization.

@LarsKotthoff And so there's no way to do that manually assuming I've defined a function to find the best combination?

I think I still don't understand what you're trying to do -- of course you can do it manually by running the steps manually. But if you have a function to find the best combination, you have a single objective that you can optimize directly.

@LarsKotthoff Exactly, my problem is that I don't know how to manually run the steps (backward selection and hyperparameter tuning). If there are examples, I'm interested. I've included my code in the post that attempts to do this. In my example, I always select the first row as the best combination, whether for tuning or feature selection. Assuming for example a function that always selects the first combination as the best combination and serves as a single objective, how do you 'optimize it directly,' as you mentioned?

You already have code for doing hyperparameter optimization for a specific feature subset above, right? Sorry, really don't know what you're looking for.

@LarsKotthoff Yes, I already have the code. One solution to my problem might be to modify the auto_tuner function code so that it 1) accepts multiple performance measures in the "measure" argument and 2) integrates my function that selects the best combination, which would amount to a single objective. But, I just looked at the auto_tuner function code and unfortunately I have never done object-oriented programming, so I do not know where to call my function in the code.

That sounds like you really want a custom objective function. If you're going to essentially run it as single-objective optimization, I don't see the point in implementing multi-objective (which would not be trivial).
